# My Website Does Not Seem to Want to Print Anything

Tags: printing, web-testing

I have developed a website and am in the process of converting most of the tables over to DataTables. In testing out one of the DataTable features the Print button, I discovered that nothing would print except the Title of the web page. At first I thought it was an issue with DataTables, but after playing around I've discovered that none of my pages seem to want to print. I'm testing with Chrome because it has the Print Preview, but I can right-click on any page in my site and select Print... and I get the same behavior -- only the Title of the web page displays.  Has anybody experienced anything like this before? Here's a link to my site:

[JCPS DMC](https://assessment.jefferson.kyschools.us/DMC/)

Even on the home page, try right clicking and select Print and you'll see what I mean.  Please tell me this is some super-easy that I just don't know about -- some setting that I've overlooked. I will be happy to provide any support information you need, but I don't even know what that would be... :(

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing...apparently at some point I included a css script in my Master page (the site is developed using asp.net).  In the css I had this little gem which was blocking anything from being printed:

```
@media print { 
body  
{
    visibility: hidden;
    border-top: hidden;
    width: 50%;
}

.noPrint
{
    display: none !important;
}

ol
{
    display: none;
}

.printSection, .printSection *
{
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
}

.printSection
{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
}
```

Not even sure why I put that in there, but I removed it and everything is working peachy now...